# My prefix prays a lot, My suffix has the key

Tags: riddle, rhyme

> My prefix prays a lot,
>
> My suffix has the key.
>
> My infix is on the top,
>
> I always like to copy.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I think the word is

> '**MONKEY**'

---

My prefix prays a lot,

> 'MONK'

My suffix has the key.

> Literally 'KEY'

My infix is on the top,

> Also literally 'ON'

I always like to copy.

> A reference to [Monkey see, monkey do](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Monkey_see,_monkey_do) which is a saying meaning to copy without knowing why.